# Use of uninitialised value of size 8 in spell-checker

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I wrote a spell-checker that uses a trie to store and check words for misspellings. It loads a textfile dictionary into memory, accepts word(s) to check for spelling errors and unloads the memory. The program compiles successfully, but when run produces a segmentation fault. Based on valgrind the problem seems to be the use of an uninitialised value in my insert function.

```
//If word not present, inserts word into trie
//If the word is a prefix of a node, marks the "leaf node" (end-of-word node)
void insert(struct node *root, const char *word)
{
int length = strlen(word);
int index = 0;

//start from root node
struct node *tempNode = root;

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    //if the current letter in word is a letter
    if(word[i] != '\'')

        //convert the alphabet to it's respective index number
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(tolower(word[i]));

    else
        //assign index number 27 (for apostrophe)
        index = INPUT_SIZE;

    //create a new node if path doesn't exist (is NULL)
    if(!(tempNode->children[index]))
        tempNode->children[index] = getNode();

        //go to next node  
        tempNode = tempNode->children[index];
        }
    //mark last node as leaf
    tempNode->isWord = true;
}
```

insert (places word in trie) is called by load (moves words from dictionary txt file into memory):

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
//initialise variables
char ch;
char word[LENGTH] = "";
int counter = 0;

struct node *root = getNode();

//open file to start inserting words
FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");

//load words in dictionary into memory
while (EOF)
{
    while((ch = fgetc(file)) != '\n')
    {
        word[counter] = ch;
        counter++;
    }
    //whole word found, insert word and reset counter, increment word count
    insert(root, word);
    counter = 0;
    word_Count++;
}

//close all open files if EOF is reached, else loading has failed- return false
if(EOF == true)
    {
    fileLoaded = true;
    fclose(file);
    return true;
    }
else return false;
}
```

and getNode() which creates a new node initialised to NULL:

```
    //Returns new trie node initialised to NULL
    struct node *getNode(void)
    {
    //initialise new node
    struct node *newNode = NULL;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    //proceed if enough memory to allocate
    if(newNode) 
    {
    //initialise pointers
    for(int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++)
        newNode->children[i] = NULL;

    newNode->isWord = false;
    }
    else return false;

    return newNode;
    }
```

The definition of struct node :

```
    //Returns new trie node initialised to NULL
struct node *getNode(void)
{
    //initialise new node
    struct node *newNode = NULL;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    //proceed if enough memory to allocate
    if(newNode) 
    {
        //initialise pointers
        for(int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++)
            newNode->children[i] = NULL;

        newNode->isWord = false;
    }
    else return false;

    return newNode;
}
```

The error according to valgrind:

```
    Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9334==    at 0x4011DD: insert (dictionary.c:84)
==9334==    by 0x4014D1: load (dictionary.c:188)
==9334==    by 0x40095D: main (speller.c:40)
==9334==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==9334==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9334==    by 0x4010CB: getNode (dictionary.c:40)
==9334==    by 0x4011E7: insert (dictionary.c:85)
==9334==    by 0x4014D1: load (dictionary.c:188)
==9334==    by 0x40095D: main (speller.c:40)
==9334== 
==9334== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==9334==    at 0x4011D5: insert (dictionary.c:84)
==9334==    by 0x4014D1: load (dictionary.c:188)
==9334==    by 0x40095D: main (speller.c:40)
==9334==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==9334==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9334==    by 0x4010CB: getNode (dictionary.c:40)
==9334==    by 0x4011E7: insert (dictionary.c:85)
==9334==    by 0x4014D1: load (dictionary.c:188)
==9334==    by 0x40095D: main (speller.c:40)
==9334== 
==9334== Invalid read of size 8
==9334==    at 0x4011D5: insert (dictionary.c:84)
==9334==    by 0x4014D1: load (dictionary.c:188)
==9334==    by 0x40095D: main (speller.c:40)
==9334==  Address 0x91 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==9334== 
==9334== 
==9334== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==9334==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x91
==9334==    at 0x4011D5: insert (dictionary.c:84)
==9334==    by 0x4014D1: load (dictionary.c:188)
==9334==    by 0x40095D: main (speller.c:40)
```

valgrind was run with --leak-check=full, --leak-check=full and --show-leak-kinds=all. I've tried referencing similar errors from previous posts but the difference in context makes it difficult to pinpoint what I should do. Line 84 is the one that reads  if(!(tempNode->children[index])). This seems (to me) to be the root cause of the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Your debugger might tell your more

Comment: What is struct node? Is children an array of pointers?

Comment: A [MCVE] might help here.

Comment: I've added struct node's definition in. Thank you for asking. @Elan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while((ch = fgetc(file)) != '\n')
{
    word[counter] = ch;
    counter++;
}
//whole word found, insert word and reset counter, increment word count
insert(root, word);
```

This is the part of your code that is causing Undefined Behavior.

Your string `word` is not null terminated but `insert` expects it to be (since the first thing it does is call `strlen` which expects a null terminated string).

Simple fix would be

```
word[counter] = '\0';
```

before call to `insert` assuming everything is in bounds.